# http-server-usr/bin/env : node : no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, web-services, npm, httpserver, npm-install

When I type the http-server command getting this error showing that
usr/bin/env : node : no such file or directory . Why getting this problem. How can i solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This solution worked for me: [Thread from askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/464405).

Ubuntu and some Linux distributions install node's interpreter as `/usr/bin/nodejs`, and not `/usr/local/bin/node`.

You can solve this issue installing the nodejs-legacy package which creates a symlink from `/usr/bin/nodejs` to `/usr/bin/node`.

Solution:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs-legacy
```